# Style the parent of the current element

Tags: html, css

In this code, I want my `ul` to have a border line colored with the activate `li` color. For example, if the `.activate` element is gray, the `ul` border bottom must be gray. How can I accomplish this with the markup below?

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="gray"><a href="#">All</a></li>
        <li class="blue"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="activate orange"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="green"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You won't be able to do this with CSS only.

Comment: Are you happy to see a jQuery solution? Or did you want to know if it was achievable with CSS only?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[There is no CSS parent selector.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/139010) Just slap a class on the `<ul>` when you want to style it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no cross-browser compatible only CSS solution as of today, here is one that is using jQuery:

**Fiddle Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/robertp/M9SGU/

**Markup:**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="gray"><a href="#">All</a></li>
    <li class="blue"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="orange"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="green"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#menu').on('click', 'li', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var $item = $(event.currentTarget);
    $item.siblings().removeClass('active');
    $item.addClass('active');

    $item.parent().css('border', '1px solid ' + $item.css('color'));
});
```

**Styling:**

```
.gray,
.gray a {
    color: gray;
}
.blue,
.blue a {
    color: blue;
}
.orange,
.orange a {
    color: orange;
}
.green,
.green a{
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's possible with the CSS4 selectors, although they are not standard at all at the moment.

```
ul!>li.activate.gray {border-bottom-color:gray}
ul!>li.activate.blue {border-bottom-color:blue}
ul!>li.activate.orange {border-bottom-color:orange}
ul!>li.activate.green {border-bottom-color:green}
```

[W3C description](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/):

`E! > F an E element parent of an F element`